# Using Highcharts display donut hightchart having dynamic data

Tags: angularjs, highcharts

I am new to the highcharts. I am using donut highchart where in  the below provided link we can get the static data

http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/3.1.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/3d-pie-donut/

But i have a no. of data in the same format as

```
Highcharts.chart('container5',{
     chart: {
        type: 'pie',
        options3d: {
            enabled: true,
            alpha: 45
        }
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Daily Report'
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: '3D donut'
    },
    plotOptions: {
        pie: {
            innerSize: 100,
            depth: 45
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Amount',
        data: [$rootScope.oprep2]
    }]

})
```

Here $rootScope.oprep2 is the data which in the array format as per the format shown / given in the demo as

[image]

in the above picture you can the line number 1025 which is in the required format.

[image]

the above pic shows the open array which contains data as unitno and amountpaid

My Query is, that the data is not displaying in the chart. So any idea, which will help me a lot. Here is the view as daily report

[image]

Here is my data

```
Array[11] =>
Array[2]=>
 0:"001"
 1:180
Array[2]=>
 0:"007"
 1:4570
Array[2]=>
 0:"008"
 1:1060
Array[2]=>
 0:"026"
 1:180
```

Each array is seperated by ,

Comment: Can you paste your data here? Or at least a sample of it.

Comment: @stpoa I have edited my question. can you please check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i have gone through your code, i see that your getting array of array, but you are assigning that data again with array which is not getting the chart. Instead of joining, separation, try to remove the array assign it directly.

```
data:$rootScope.oprep2
```

but not

```
data:[$rootScope.oprep2]
```

Comment: Thanks @Nitin Agarwal. It works great. Just a small mistake screwed me.. Thanks a lot